# "Not" not defined while using Julia DataFrames

Tags: dataframe, julia, ijulia-notebook

While going through the tutorials of DataFrames from MLJ, I encountered the following error

```
julia> b2 = select(boston, Not(:NOx))
ERROR: UndefVarError: Not not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Link to the tutorial: https://alan-turing-institute.github.io/DataScienceTutorials.jl/data/dataframe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This operation should work:

```
julia> b2 = select(boston, Not(:NOx))
506×13 DataFrame
 Row │ Crim     Zn       Indus    Chas   Rm       A ⋯
     │ Float64  Float64  Float64  Int64  Float64  F ⋯
─────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.00632     18.0     2.31      0    6.575  6 ⋯
   2 │ 0.02731      0.0     7.07      0    6.421  7
   3 │ 0.02729      0.0     7.07      0    7.185  6
  ⋮  │    ⋮        ⋮        ⋮       ⋮       ⋮       ⋱
 504 │ 0.06076      0.0    11.93      0    6.976  9
 505 │ 0.10959      0.0    11.93      0    6.794  8 ⋯
 506 │ 0.04741      0.0    11.93      0    6.03   8
                       8 columns and 500 rows omitted
```

Please make sure that you are using the latest DataFrames.jl version. Go to package manager mode by pressing `]` in the Julia REPL and then write:

```
(@v1.6) pkg> st DataFrames
      Status `~/.julia/environments/v1.6/Project.toml`
  [a93c6f00] DataFrames v0.22.5
```

Your version number should be 0.22.5 (as of time of this writing).

If it is some older version you probably have some other package that restricts updating of DataFrames.jl. [Here](https://bkamins.github.io/julialang/2020/05/11/package-version-restrictions.html) is a post describing how to diagnose such situations.

Comment: I tried installing v0.22.5 for DataFrames which seem to had a conflict with the version of RDatasets, so then I tried updating all the packages present, and that solved the problem.